# Forward SSH traffic to remote server

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

On my linux VM i have two IPs

192.168.11.88
192.168.11.99

I want ssh traffic from 192.168.11.99 on port 8889 to forward traffic to remote server 172.16.5.80 on port 22

How to achieve this with IPTables

Thanks

---

As suggested by FelixJN. I used socat utility intead of IPtables, below configuration works and traffic is forward to remote server.

```
[Unit]
Description=forwards local port 192.168.56.70:8889 to 192.168.56.70:22
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat -lf /var/log/socat-ssh.log TCP-LISTEN:8889,fork,bind=192.168.56.71 TCP:192.168.56.70:22
Restart=On-Failure
RestartSec=5
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Can't you just use `ssh -R` and/or `ssh -L`? Must it specifically be with iptables?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on finding the solution youself. However, please don't edit your question to contain the answer - write [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Thanks. but all credits goes @FelixJN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For forwarding ports, `socat` might be the simplest

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8889,fork,bind=192.168.11.99 TCP:172.16.5.80:22
```

Listens on port `8889` but for local IP `192.168.11.99` only. Forwards all incoming traffic to `172.16.5.80:22`

---

Possible systemd-service file (`/etc/systemd/system/socat-ssh.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=forwards local port 192.168.11.99:8889 to 172.16.5.80:22
After=ssh

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/socat -lf /var/log/socat-ssh.log TCP-LISTEN:8889,fork,bind=192.168.11.99 TCP:172.16.5.80:22
Restart=On-Failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

(check path of `socat` for your system)

Enable (for autostart on boot) and start (for first time initialization):

```
systemctl enable socat-ssh
systemctl start socat-ssh
```

Comment: I need something permanent, like deploy and forget about it, do i have to run this command everytime the system reboots?

Comment: @OmiPenguin Do you have `systemd` up and running? I just made it a service to be started after `ssh` and with the above as `ExecStart` command (using full path and a specific logfile `-lf /var/log/my_socat.log`)

Comment: Thanks FelixJN, It works i can ssh to remote server if i use the assigned IP and port. But the only issue it doesn't start on reboot. Even though i enabled it

Comment: Ok fixed the issue, I set "After=multi-user.target" and user=root in [Service] section. and on reboot service become active. Also crontab can also be used if someone dont want to create systemd service. I will paste the content of files in question area.